# My praying mantis won’t molt? It’s been 3 months?

Tags: insects, molting

My praying mantis hasn’t molted in three months. She’s only molted twice in her life. The second time she molted she molded wrong and her front hands got stuck in skin so she can’t grab food. So I’ve been hand feeding her cat food (I read online that’s what you should hand feed them) until she molted again and was able to feed herself. However, she hasn’t molted again. She’s supposed to be a giant Asian mantis. and she’s tiny. I mist her everyday. And she lives in a huge habitat. Also, she has a bunch of dried cat food on her front legs now I don’t know how to take off. I feel terrible :( What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is normal, just keep feeding her. My spiny flower mantis hasn't molted for about
four to five weeks (usually it's about every two) she will molt on her own time. If you
want to, you can feed her a lot of food, and that should speed it up, also keep the cage
a bit more humid when she's about to molt.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a little late now, but just for future reference if you plan on keeping mantises: never ever feed them cat food. They eat live insects like flies (fruit flies, green bottle flies, blue bottle flies), wax worms, small grasshoppers. These should be live and moving, as they hunt for these type of insects out in the wild. They won't be interested in eating dead insects. I believe that your mantis didn't develop properly due to the wrong food and didn't get the right nutrients. Also, the right environment is essential as well. Research the temperature and humidity your mantis should live in and make sure you mist the enclosure regularly or use a heat mat if they require higher temperature.

Comment: Hi Adele, welcome to Pets ^.^

Answer (score -1):

I recommend feeding her live insects. Her developmental problem may be due to her lack of essential nutrients.

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange :) This is counter to the upvoted answer - If you could add a source to your it would really improve it. You might also want to read [answer] for some tips on a great answer.